# What kind of financing options are there for large personal projects?

Tags: united-states, financing

I'm doing pretty decently on my personal finance goals. I've acquired a personal home with more than 50% equity, a second home for income with about 30% equity, and have several other investments and a business that produce income.

What I have in mind now is to use a recently acquired cash hoard for a bigger project. I want to level up. For example, there is a half acre for sale down the street. It has a dumpy house on it, but is rezoned for apartments or a fourplex. I can buy it now and pay 50% down, but I don't think typical home loans would be the right place to finance a building project like a fourplex or an apartment building. If I refurbed the house and built a fourplex behind it, it would probably require about $1.5M in financing. If I went big and demolished the house and built a large apartment building on it, it would probably be $5M-$10M financing needed (maybe more, I've not done all my homework on this kind of project yet).

What kind of financing am I looking for and were do I go to get it? The perfect option allows me to keep 100% ownership, but I'm not completely averse to "investor" kinds of arrangements.

Comment: Start talking to banks about construction loans or look for investors for a multi-family sindication. You didn't mention the country/location, so hard to pinpoint anything more specific.

Comment: United States. Thanks @littleadv

Comment: That isn't usually considered a "personal project". It's treated as a business project, even if you are being your own primary contractor and doing a lot of the work yourself, and even if you are going to just give the space to relatives rather than rent our or sell the units. If you want to do it with other people's money, you are probably going to have to meet agreed-upon deadlines for specific checkpoints.

Comment: If you are about to invest several million, it would be wise to ask a professional rather than someone anonymous on the internet.  Banks can and will help you. It they refuse to, it's almost certainly for good reasons (that the banks internal checks deem your needs unrealistic or too risky).